# How to display the values of each array in larger array?

Tags: arrays, swift, string

I have

```
    var array = [["Chinese"],["Italian"],["Thai"]]
```

and I'm looking to set the names of these three array values to label in a table list.

I simply can't set my

```
cell.namelabel.text = array.string
```

or something like that.

Would anyone be able to recommend a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**-** A quick and dirty way to get it done is here.....

```
var array = [["Chinese"],["Italian"],["Thai"]]
cell.namelabel.text = array.string  = array[0][0]
```

**-** One can also iterate using `for-in` over the Array of Arrays (ie. array) here and access them but thats just one way to do it.

**-** One can also try to fetch all the values in the array to a `single dimension array`, so the access gets easier if thats the motive of the code.

```
var array = [["Chinese"],["Italian"],["Thai"]]

 var valArray: [String] = []

 for value in array
 {
     for innerValue in value
     {
        valArray.append(innerValue)
     }
 }

 print(valArray)
```

Comment: The bottom bit can also be done with `let oneD = array.flatMap { $0 }`.

Comment: @0x7fffffff Good one !!

Answer (score 1):

You could try `array.description`. Not quite sure if that is what you are looking for.