# Trouble inserting struct arrays into one array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, struct

So I have a struct that I am using to populate certain arrays.

```
    let mcdonalds = restaurant(name: "Mcdonalds")
    let burgerking = restaurant(name: "Burger King")
    let vinsetta = restaurant(name: "Vinsetta Garage")
    let chinaone = restaurant(name: "China One Buffet")
    let pandaexpress = restaurant(name: "Panda Express")
    let olivegarden = restaurant(name: "Olive Garden")
    let salvatore = restaurant(name: "Salvatorre Scallopinis")


    american = [mcdonalds, burgerking]
    burgers = [vinsetta]
    chinese = [chinaone, pandaexpress]
    italian = [olivegarden, salvatore]
    allRestaurantTypeArray = [american, burgers, chinese, italian]
```

unfortunately, when I attempt to combine my american,burgers,chinese, & italian arrays into the allrestaruranttypearray, I am greeted with a "cannot assigned a value of type "[[restaurant]]" to a value of type 'NSArray'".

would you be able to recommend any changes?

update:

[image]

Comment: You should name your structs starting with a capital letter

Comment: would that change anything?  or just better code syntax?

Comment: There is no better syntax. It is a convention.

Comment: `[american, chinese, burgers].flatmap{$0}`

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to do a `flatMap` here ...
[image]

You are making an array of arrays which is what `[[restaurant]]` means.

`flatMap` will "flatten" them out.

```
struct Restaurant {
    var name = ""
}
let mcdonalds = Restaurant(name: "Mcdonalds")
let burgerking = Restaurant(name: "Burger King")
let vinsetta = Restaurant(name: "Vinsetta Garage")
let chinaone = Restaurant(name: "China One Buffet")
let pandaexpress = Restaurant(name: "Panda Express")
let olivegarden = Restaurant(name: "Olive Garden")
let salvatore = Restaurant(name: "Salvatorre Scallopinis")


let american = [mcdonalds, burgerking]
let burgers = [vinsetta]
let chinese = [chinaone, pandaexpress]
let italian = [olivegarden, salvatore]
let allRestaurantTypeArray = [american, burgers, chinese, italian]

let flattened = allRestaurantTypeArray.flatMap{$0}



flattened.first?.name  // "Mcdonalds"
flattened.last?.name   // "Salvatorre Scallopinis"
```

I've updated it to help you out even better:

[image]

You have to apply the `flatmap` to the array of arrays

Comment: I know flatmap works with numbers, but can i use this function to flatten arrays with struct instances or strings?

Comment: @jonpeter my example is strings

Comment: @jonpeter look at the comment at another question of yours http://stackoverflow.com/a/33140261/2303865

Comment: I attempted that method but was unsuccessful.  I wanted to try a different possibility, so I thought this attempt would be better.  Which solution would you recommend @LeoDabus?

Comment: The fllatMap comment . Same as suggested by jeef

Comment: I apologize for the questions, but I have one more concept Q.  So the american, burgers,chinese, and italian will be in a tableview.  if i select american, i want mcdonalds and burger king to appear on a second table.  How am i to keep the organizations of american to mcdonals and burger king with that flatmap?

Comment: Your struct needs to have the ability to best the.  Not array but arrays of arrays. You have to figure it which you want (and you could support both) but you can't be both flat and nested at the same time. I'm going to sleep but if you post your struts I'll look in the morn

Comment: appreciate it, night.